# rewrite and redirect using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an old php dynamic web site that uses index.php to generate everything. I changed  the index.php file to product.php and made keyword rich url using product.php. The keyword riche works. Now i need to make a 301 redirect in the htaccess so that the indexed links will be redirect to product.php

This works

```
# Rewrite keyword-rich URLs
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/.*-([0-9]+)\.html$                   product.php?lang=$1&cat=$2 [L]

# Rewrite keyword-rich URLs
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/.*-([0-9]+)/.*-sc([0-9]+)\.html$     product.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&subCat=$3 [L]
```

but i tried to add before these rules this but it is not changing the url

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^index\.php?(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^product.php?$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am using mamp to do my testing

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (before your existing rules):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ product.php [R=301,L]
```

Note the `\` before the `?` in the condition, then the space between the `^` and `product.php`. The query string will automatically get appended. You don't need to backreference it.

Comment: unfortunately it is not redirecting me to product.php it remain on index.php wich i am planning to remove. Any other ideas

Comment: @isabellegagnier err my bad, you need to change the beginning of the match to `\ /+` instead

Comment: still nothing. here is my exact url http://localhost:8888/desirsDeProvence/index.php?lang=Fr&cat=3&subCat=27 i need it to change to http://localhost:8888/desirsDeProvence/product.php?lang=Fr&cat=3&subCat=27 then i assume that my pretty url rules will take over

Comment: @isabellegagnier How about just `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ product.php [R=301,L]` then if you've got stuff in front of `/index.php`.

Comment: Ok i think we are getting somewhere but now this is where it sent me i have this in my product.php file first line is the head section http://localhost:8888/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/desirsDeProvence/product.php?lang=Fr&cat=3&subCat=27 i need to get ride of Applications/MAMP/htdocs why is that htere i have this in my product .php <head>
  <base href="http://localhost:8888/desirsDeProvence/product.php" /> but this makes my other rules work

Comment: @isabellegagnier at the top of the rules add: `RewriteBase /desirsDeProvence/`